# Problem with IAutoInitialize Interface from Prism.AppModel causing my popups to have no text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, popup, prism

I do use Prism.Forms nuget package in my project.
[Package Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz8uu.png)

Today i updated the package and the following error appeared:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IAutoInitialize' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Then i tried to run the App after removing the IAutoInitialize inheritance from my view model and found out that my custom popups had no more text being displayed. *(I checked my ShowDialog() calls and yes, i am passing the text to the dialog page constructor)*

below is my view model code where the problem with IAutoInitialize Appeared:

```
public class CustomPopupViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware, IAutoInitialize
{
    public event Action<IDialogParameters> RequestClose;
    public DelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ConfirmCommand { get; set; }

    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Title, value); }
    }

    private string _Message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Message, value); }
    }

    private string _CancelMsg;
    public string CancelMsg
    {
        get { return _CancelMsg; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _CancelMsg, value); }
    }

    private string _ConfirmMsg;
    public string ConfirmMsg
    {
        get { return _ConfirmMsg; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _ConfirmMsg, value); }
    }

    public CustomPopupViewModel()
    {
        CancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(CancelTapped);
        ConfirmCommand = new DelegateCommand(ConfirmTapped);
    }

    private void ConfirmTapped()
    {
        RequestClose(new DialogParameters { { typeof(bool).Name, true } });
    }

    private void CancelTapped()
    {
        RequestClose(new DialogParameters { { typeof(bool).Name, false } });
    }

    public bool CanCloseDialog() => true;

    public void OnDialogClosed() { }

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters) { }
}
```

I think that removing IAutoInitialize interface was the cause of no text being displayed in my popups.
My question is, where is IAutoInitialize located after the 8.0.0.1909 version update or how to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the release notes [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases), IAutoInitialize was removed as of release 8.0.0.1909 (Oct 21, 2020):

"Removed IAutoInitialize - recommended migration use Prism.Magician on Sponsor Connect"